# How to avoid getting Hydration Errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I keep on getting hyrdration errors, it might be hae something to do with the imported audiomotion component.

```
"use client"

import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import AudioMotionAnalyzer from 'audiomotion-analyzer';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { Progress } from '@/components/ui/progress';
import { FastForward, Flower, Pause, Play, Rewind, Zap } from 'lucide-react';
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import Image from "next/image";

const MeditationPage: React.FC = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);
  const visualizerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [audioMotion, setAudioMotion] = useState<AudioMotionAnalyzer | null>(null);
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [videoTime, setVideoTime] = useState<number>(0);
  const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Mark component as mounted (and thus running in the client)
    setIsClient(true);

    // Ensure audio visualizer setup only occurs client-side
    if (isClient && visualizerRef.current && !audioMotion && videoRef.current) {
      try {
        const newAudioMotion = new AudioMotionAnalyzer(visualizerRef.current, {
          source: videoRef.current,
          bgAlpha: 0,
          overlay: true,
          showBgColor: false,
          showScaleX: false,
          showScaleY: false,
        });

        newAudioMotion.registerGradient('neonBlue', {
          bgColor: '#00000000', // Keeping the background transparent
          colorStops: [
            { color: '#e0f9ff', pos: 0 },   // Very light cyan blue at the start
            { color: '#80d8ff', pos: 0.5 }, // Light cyan blue in the middle
            { color: '#00b0ff', pos: 1 }    // Slightly darker cyan blue towards the end
          ]
        });

        newAudioMotion.setOptions({ gradient: 'neonBlue', lineWidth: 10, });
        setAudioMotion(newAudioMotion);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("AudioMotion initialization failed:", error);
      }
    }
  }, [audioMotion, isClient]); // Now depends on isClient too

  const togglePlayPause = () => {
    if (videoRef.current) {
      videoRef.current[isPlaying ? 'pause' : 'play']();
      setIsPlaying(!isPlaying);
    }
  };

  const skipTime = (seconds: number) => {
    if (videoRef.current) {
      videoRef.current.currentTime += seconds;
    }
  };

  // Update video time for the progress bar
  useEffect(() => {
    if (videoRef.current) {
      const video = videoRef.current;
      const updateVideoTime = () => setVideoTime(video.currentTime);
      video.addEventListener('timeupdate', updateVideoTime);
      return () => video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', updateVideoTime);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 xs:grid-cols-9 gap-4">
      <div className="px-4 lg:px-8 py-4"> {/* Enhanced spacing around the heading */}
        <div className="bg-gradient-to-r from-teal-500 to-emerald-500 p-6 rounded-lg shadow-xl">
          <div className="flex items-center space-x-4">
            <div className="flex-shrink-0 text-white">
              <Flower size={24} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <h1 className="text-xl font-semibold text-white">Breathing</h1>
              <p className="text-pink-200">
                Find peace through breathing in and out
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div className="flex justify-center items-center mt-8">
        <div className="relative rounded overflow-hidden border-4 border-cyan-500 shadow-lg">
          <Image
            src="/med2.png"
            alt="Description of the image"
            width={300}
            height={300}
            className="object-cover"
          />
          <div className="absolute bottom-0 right-0 p-2 text-sm text-white bg-black bg-opacity-50 rounded-tl">
            by Thera
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center text-white mt-8">
        <div ref={visualizerRef} className="w-full h-30"></div>
        <div className="neon-lamp w-full mb-8"></div>
        <video ref={videoRef} src="10 MIN Guided Meditation To Clear Your Mind & Start New Positive Habits.mp3" crossOrigin="anonymous" preload="auto" style={{ display: 'none' }}></video>
        
        <div className="w-full bg-gray-300 rounded-full overflow-hidden">
          <div className="h-2 bg-cyan-500 rounded-full" style={{ width: `${(videoTime / (videoRef.current?.duration || 1)) * 100}%` }}></div>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center space-x-4 mt-8">
        <Button className="text-xl font-medium px-4 py-2 rounded-lg bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700 transition-colors" onClick={() => skipTime(-10)}> <Rewind size={24} color="white" /> </Button>
        <Button className={`w-16 h-16 rounded-full flex items-center justify-center text-xl font-medium ${isPlaying ? 'bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700' : 'bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700'} transition-colors`} onClick={togglePlayPause}>
          {isPlaying ? <Pause size={24} color="white" /> : <Play size={24} color="white" />}
        </Button>
        <Button className="text-xl font-medium px-4 py-2 rounded-lg bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-700 transition-colors" onClick={() => skipTime(10)}> <FastForward size={24} color="white" /> </Button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default MeditationPage;
```

I was expecting no hydration errors. The page works with all the functioanlity, however, the 3 errors as the bottom of the screen is annoying to look at.

`Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

See more info here: [https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error`](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error%60)

The error callstack:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Call Stack throwOnHydrationMismatch node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (7088:8) throwOnHydrationMismatch node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (7133:6) tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (16524:4) updateHostComponent$1 node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (18427:13) apply node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (20498:13) dispatchEvent node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (20547:15) apply node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (20622:28) invokeGuardedCallback node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26813:6) beginWork node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25637:11) performUnitOfWork node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25623:4) workLoopConcurrent node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25579:8) renderRootConcurrent node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24432:37) callback node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (256:33) workLoop node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (225:13) flushWork node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (534:20)

Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Call Stack throwOnHydrationMismatch node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (7088:8) throwOnHydrationMismatch node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (7133:6) tryToClaimNextHydratableInstance node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (16524:4) updateHostComponent$1 node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (18427:13) beginWork$1 node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26791:13) beginWork node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25637:11) performUnitOfWork node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25623:4) workLoopConcurrent node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25579:8) renderRootConcurrent node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24432:37) callback node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (256:33) workLoop node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (225:13) flushWork node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (534:20)

Unhandled Runtime Error Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.

Call Stack updateHostRoot node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (16472:56) updateHostRoot node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (18410:13) beginWork$1 node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (26791:13) beginWork node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25637:11) performUnitOfWork node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25353:4) workLoopSync node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (25308:6) renderRootSync node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24525:19) recoverFromConcurrentError node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js (24470:25) callback node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (256:33) workLoop node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (225:13) flushWork node_modules/next/dist/compiled/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js (534:20)
```

Comment: Please share the `error` trace too !

Comment: Like the error callstack?

Comment: yes, please share the error callstack !